# Pentaho unzip file

Tags: wildcard, pentaho, unzip

I have a zip folder and with two files, a.txt and b.txt, I want to bring only a.txt file, I'm using "Unzip file" step in pentaho. when I fill field "include wild card" the process don't bring any file, when I don't fill this field, the process bring all files. someboby can help me?

Comment: Most all wildcard fields in Pentaho expect a Java regex, not a regular filesystem one. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

The "Wild Card" expression will work on the file list and not on the content of the file. For e.g. As in your case, if you are having a.txt and b.txt in a zip folder named : data.zip ; using "wild card expression" in the "Unzip file" step, it will only search for pattern in the "data.zip" folder and not inside the content of data.zip. This is the reason why your code was not unzipping when you included the regular expression, since you were trying to read "a.txt" instead of searching for data.zip.

As per your case, you can try a work around !! Try unzipping the content of the data.zip into an archieve folder (or anything similar) and then using the regular expression to read only the "a.txt" file from the archieve folder; instead of trying the first step.

Hope this might work out :)